# VB how to draw to screen faster than GDI+?

Tags: vb.net, graphics, gdi+, gdi

I know there are tons of posts out there for graphics in games made in visual basic. I also know that GDI+ is not the best method for making games, but that is all I have access to at the moment.

I have made a huge game with over 3,000 lines of code that is a sort of 2D RPG game, and the game uses GDi+ for graphics. The game runs well when in 854 by 480 (at a maximum framerate of 65fps), but as the resolution increases, the framerate decreases. The framerate goes down to around 30 when playing in fullscreen (1920 by 1080).

Even though these framerates sound usable, my computer has an i7 4770k, dual gtx760s, and 16GB of ram. On a weaker computer the game has gone all the way down to 20fps when in 720p. Is there some magical way to still use GDI+ and achieve a constant 65 fps even on bad computers? Also a method that better uses powerful hardware would be great. If not GDI+ then I may be able to convert the program to use other methods.

One thing to note is that the framerate stays at the maximum on most computers when manipulating the images in game but not displaying it on the screen. This proves that the program itself is not the problem and neither is the image manipulation, just putting it on the screen at the end.

Comment: You have it in your tag, `GDI`. If you can have 30-65 fps now with `GDI` you can get around 400-800 even more.

Comment: Direct2d and DirectX

Comment: How do you use GDI? When I search it all that comes up is gdi+...